# Как в SELECT перебрать двумерный массив в Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

кто может подсказать, как в Postgres перебрать массив в select'e?

Например, есть массив

```
{{1,2,3,4,10,12},{1,4,3,3,25,14},{1,6,3,3,11,14}}
```

Мне нужно получить сумму 5 и 6 элементов, и вывести строки в порядке убывания, то есть получиться вот такое должно

```
1,2,3,4,22
1,6,3,3,25
1,4,3,3,39
```

Уточнение, это отдельные столбцы, а не строка целиком

Можно ли это сделать как-то оконной функцией, но не через функцию и цикл, а именно select'ом?
Через функцию у меня нормально все. Тут именно понять, можно ли селектом перебирать массив.

Уточнение, изначально количество элементов неизвестно, то есть жестко делать выборку array[1:1], array[1:2] и тд не получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    columns ->> 0 AS col1,
    columns ->> 1  AS col2,
    columns ->> 2  AS col3,
    columns ->> 3  AS col4,
    (columns ->> 4)::int + (columns ->> 5)::int  AS col5
FROM
    json_array_elements(array_to_json('{{1,2,3,4,10,12},{1,4,3,3,25,14},{1,6,3,3,11,14}}'::int[])) columns
ORDER BY col5;
```

Comment: как просто, спасибо большое. А то я уже ушел в дебри типа такого array_to_string(array_agg (quote_ident (f)), ', ')